# What is the screen customization alternative for LineageOS?

Tags: custom-roms, lineageos, customization, resurrection-remix-os

If you ever used **Resurrection Remix ROM** you see in the Settings app there's a Customization part where you can make some tweaks like add some buttons on navbar or maybe add a extra home/return button in another part of the screen, etc, etc... My question is, what is the alternative available for **LineageOS 16?** I'm asking because it doesn't have any customization app by default  and I need one because the Home button of my cellphone is broken (hardware stuff, not software) and when I used RR I just added a new home button on the bottom of the screen. How can I do the same for LineageOS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume Firelord wanted to type "EdXposed". EdXposed is more or less the successor of xposed. You can find it in the Magisk module repository.

Comment: See also the [tag:EdXposed] on this site which has questions on how to install on recent Android versions